# How can I create a managed metadata column that allows terms from several term sets?

Tags: managed-metadata

What I'd like to do is create a Managed Metadata column that allows terms that come from several term sets (or possibly from one group containing several term sets).

True, adding an Enterprise Keywords column does something like what I want, except that it allows terms from all groups (albeit with nicely categorized suggestions, a very useful feature) instead of just the few that I want.

True, creating an extra term set and reusing all the relevant terms kept in other term sets does produce a precise list of the terms, but it loses the categorization (which is very important for what I have in mind) because if, say, I reuse the terms in term sets A, B and C in term set D, the categories all display as [D] in the suggestion box.

TIA for any help in solving this conundrum.

Josh

Answer (score 1):

You cannot connect Managed Metadata columns to more than one anchor. That being said, your anchor can be a term, a term set, or a group. Just link your column to the root of your desired hierarchy.

If you want multiple branches to appear as one to users, you will need to build a custom field.

Comment: Louis -- a group would do the job just fine. But as far as I can see, the configuration page allows only for anchors that are term sets, not groups. Am I missing something?