# More than 1 Term set for a managed metadata column

Tags: 2013, managed-metadata, term-store

Is it possible to have a column with more than one term set associated?

I read that is possible to associate a MM column with a group but I don't know if I'm missing something

Answer (score -1):

Edit:
No
, If you want to reference multiple Term SETS then you need to use multiple fields.
[Assign multiple term sets to a single column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/70206/assign-multiple-term-sets-to-a-single-column)

If your columns say Allow the Multiple value then yes you can have more than 1 term associated it.(if you go the list settings > click on the columns then their is on check box >Multiple Value field > check it if you want)

> **If the column's definition allows multiple values, the user can select
>   more than one term**. If both the term set and the column's definition
>   allow new terms to be added, the user can also create a new term and
>   insert it at the appropriate place in the term set's hierarchy.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee559337(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: You need to read again my question... I said "More than 1 Term Set" not more than 1 term... Obviously I can activate the option in order to have multivalue in the field, but that wasn't my question...

Comment: ok when you allow it for multiple values, then you can get terms set which is associated with the site collection / have permission. you can only put the terms in the column not term set. am i missing something

Comment: When you create the Column you have to specify which term set do this column accept and from it you can set values that are in the term set you chose. My question: Can you choose more than one term set for the column in the column definition?

Comment: check the answer now

Comment: where you read you assign it multiple term sets?

Comment: I said with a group: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/36768/how-can-i-create-a-managed-metadata-column-that-allows-terms-from-several-term-s

Comment: I just tried on my vm and same result, you have to select the term / anchor till end so thats mean not more than one term set in a single column...if you need then you need multiple columns.